# Decoding Cached Chrome File

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, caching

So, somehow I made updates to my Wordpress CSS and in the process of updating, the entire style.css file was wiped clean. There's nothing.

I was able to locate the file in Chrome cache, and it gave me this.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 31 May 2016 15:21:34 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 31 May 2016 15:13:36 GMT
ETag: "601e-53424d1303eb0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 4860
Content-Type: text/css


00000000: 40 01 00 00 03 08 0c 00 e7 c3 2e 36 bb 92 2e 00  @..........6....
00000010: a9 1f 31 36 bb 92 2e 00 fa 00 00 00 48 54 54 50  ..16........HTTP
00000020: 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 00 44 61 74 65  /1.1 200 OK.Date
00000030: 3a 20 54 75 65 2c 20 33 31 20 4d 61 79 20 32 30  : Tue, 31 May 20
00000040: 31 36 20 31 35 3a 32 31 3a 33 34 20 47 4d 54 00  16 15:21:34 GMT.
00000050: 53 65 72 76 65 72 3a 20 41 70 61 63 68 65 00 4c  Server: Apache.L
00000060: 61 73 74 2d 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 3a 20 54 75  ast-Modified: Tu
00000070: 65 2c 20 33 31 20 4d 61 79 20 32 30 31 36 20 31  e, 31 May 2016 1
00000080: 35 3a 31 33 3a 33 36 20 47 4d 54 00 45 54 61 67  5:13:36 GMT.ETag
00000090: 3a 20 22 36 30 31 65 2d 35 33 34 32 34 64 31 33  : "601e-53424d13
000000a0: 30 33 65 62 30 22 00 41 63 63 65 70 74 2d 52 61  03eb0".Accept-Ra
000000b0: 6e 67 65 73 3a 20 62 79 74 65 73 00 56 61 72 79  nges: bytes.Vary
000000c0: 3a 20 41 63 63 65 70 74 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e  : Accept-Encodin
000000d0: 67 00 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69  g.Content-Encodi
000000e0: 6e 67 3a 20 67 7a 69 70 00 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74  ng: gzip.Content
000000f0: 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 34 38 36 30 00 43 6f  -Length: 4860.Co
00000100: 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 74 65 78 74  ntent-Type: text
00000110: 2f 63 73 73 00 00 00 00 f1 34 f2 83 cc 4a e9 88  /css.....4...J..
00000120: f9 ce 6c ad b9 05 74 ff 0e 00 00 00 36 39 2e 31  ..l...t.....69.1
00000130: 36 33 2e 31 36 32 2e 31 32 31 00 00 50 00 00 00  63.162.121..P...
00000140: 01 00 00 00                                      ....


00000000: 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 e4 1a db 6e e3 b8  .............n..
00000010: f5 59 fe 0a 16 c1 36 c9 c0 f2 28 b2 9d 8b 03 2c  .Y....6...(....,
00000020: 0a 14 58 a0 40 51 14 68 9f 8a be 50 12 65 71 23  ..X.@Q.h...P.eq#
00000030: 89 1a 89 ce 65 06 f3 ef 3d bc 49 a4 44 c9 c9 60  ....e...=.I.D..`
00000040: 31 2f dd 59 c7 36 79 ce e1 b9 5f 28 7f fe b4 fa  1/.Y.6y..._(....
00000050: 8d 96 a4 c6 15 39 a0 8e bf 95 64 93 76 dd ea df  .....9....d.v...
00000060: 05 a9 08 fa 87 5c fd 6b 4b b2 9a 53 bc fa f4 79  .....\.kK..S...y
00000070: b5 2a 78 55 ae 51 c2 b2 b7 35 ca e8 f3 1a 75 0d  .*xU.Q...5....u.
00000080: ae d7 08 37 4d 49 38 6c fc 4e 52 78 a3 79 0b a8  ...7MI8l.NRx.y..
00000090: eb 55 71 b3 46 45 0c af 2d bc 76 f0 da c3 eb 76  .Uq.FE..-.v....v
000000a0: 8d 1a 80 2c 59 fa f4 e5 c4 38 80 35 2d fc c1 40  ...,Y....8.5-..@
000000b0: 25 49 5a f8 9b b6 ac 7e ab e0 43 96 b5 a4 eb 00  %IZ....~..C.....
000000c0: 96 1e d7 28 a5 00 8a 52 96 01 6c 46 80 89 2c 87  ...(...R..lF..,.
000000d0: 83 09 c0 d1 0a b6 69 0d 80 4f 49 b6 5e 7d 01 a6  ......i..OI.^}..
000000e0: e0 7f 5c 35 eb 55 57 e1 12 40 3b de d2 27 22 df  ..\5.UW..@;..'".
000000f0: 59 0d c0 dd 29 11 7f 80 0d 0e dc 3e e3 76 bd 82  Y...)......>.v..
00000100: 85 13 50 81 13 48 cd 09 2c 64 e2 08 0e ef d9 1a  ..P..H..,d......
00000110: 31 f8 7c 82 57 49 d7 ab 9c 92 32 eb 84 b0 39 6b  1.|.WI....2...9k
00000120: e1 f4 12 27 82 9b 92 1c 49 0d a7 73 9c 94 82 4f  ...'....I..s...O
00000130: dc 70 ca 80 41 ae 74 c5 73 c6 80 18 2f 08 06 7a  .p..A.t.s.../..z
00000140: 1c c4 e4 05 bc 00 01 b7 9c a6 02 05 77 34 93 98  ............w4..
00000150: f5 33 06 01 32 c2 31 2d 3b 21 62 42 00 07 0e 3e  .3..2.1-;!bB...>
00000160: 9e 40 51 08 de 0d f5 95 a0 0a cc 22 41 56 be 1f  .@Q........"AV..
00000170: 5b 26 c4 5a 55 a4 06 71 6a 0c 16 62 27 de 9c 80  [&.ZU..qj..b'...
00000180: dd f6 94 00 23 1d 18 48 32 d6 9d aa 0a b7 6f c0  ....#..H2.....o.
00000190: 13 15 a6 82 cf 4f c0 c3 29 a3 0c 34 02 9c 30 f4  .....O..)..4..0.
000001a0: 6d 85 e0 3f d8 38 d2 fa 80 a2 47 f9 b5 01 ab d0  m..?.8....G.....
000001b0: fa d8 7f 4f 58 0b 27 f7 5f 73 56 f3 b0 a3 5f c1  ...OX.'._sV..._.
000001c0: 6f 6e a2 e8 97 61 f1 00 16 2a 48 4b b9 5a 7a 26  on...a...*HK.Zz&
000001d0: 42 6c 5c 86 b8 a4 47 a0 9e e0 8e 94 b4 26 8f ab  Bl\...G......&..
000001e0: ef ab 89 4a 7a 55 58 a2 23 a3 8e 39 1d d8 2a d0  ...JzUX.#..9..*.
000001f0: 42 6b 89 32 da 35 25 7e 3b 28 1f 94 27 0a 23 e9  Bk.2.5%~;(..'.#.
00000200: 5d c1 45 58 10 7a 2c 80 e7 1b b9 ab cc df ef 77  ].EX.z,........w
00000210: 20 a1 88 94 03 aa 99 e6 d8 f2 66 f4 45 03 ca af   .........f.E...
00000220: 9d 17 e8 90 10 70 1e 62 47 c1 01 e7 d2 ed be f4  .....p.bG.......
00000230: 7b 5f d4 92 a6 96 82 0e 89 50 e3 e5 e5 a3 bb d0  {_.......P......
00000240: d3 97 ae a7 c1 95 59 c2 94 95 25 6e 3a 60 d5 7c  ......Y...%n:`.|
00000250: b2 ad 16 42 f0 a6 c6 98 40 00 02 a9 37 fa 6b f8  ...B....@...7.k.
00000260: 42 33 5e 28 33 a2 3f d1 aa 61 2d c7 35 97 80 9f  B3^(3.?..a-.5...
00000270: 3f 01 04 ad 11 64 04 4b 73 09 4e 9f 84 ee eb ec  ?....d.Ks.N.....
00000280: 80 2e e2 38 56 47 f5 aa ec dd c1 22 fc e8 ba 18  ...8VG....."....
00000290: f8 1f 67 8f 13 0e 6e ef a3 e6 55 2f d3 da 2c 6f  ..g...n...U/..,o
000002a0: 63 b9 1a 8c 3d d2 76 c1 9d c1 93 8b 39 ae 68 09  c...=.v.....9.h.
000002b0: 76 bf fc ad 95 4c fd 0b d7 1d fa 67 cb 2e 2d 98  v....L.....g..-.
000002c0: 17 cd ee 2e 8a 8c 9e 4b 06 fe 7d 71 7f 7f ff 38  .......K..}q...8
000002d0: 75 90 78 a3 c5 e4 e4 95 87 2d a4 00 f0 71 c1 0c  u.x......-...q..
000002e0: 03 37 ad 80 89 bf 93 23 4d 68 49 f9 9b 52 b1 ca  .7.....#MhI..R..
000002f0: 8c 88 e9 4c 29 83 db af 74 a3 69 fe d6 b0 63 8b  ...L)...t.i...c.
00000300: 9b e2 4d e8 db 9f 52 35 85 73 52 06 46 98 ed 76  ..M...R5.sR.F..v
00000310: 0b df 1c 81 6f 23 e5 04 c5 8d 4d 4c e9 71 2b 35  ....o#....ML.q+5
00000320: 2d 36 e3 e9 66 7c 6b 36 b7 9e cd d8 6c ee a6 9b  -6..f|k6....l...
00000330: 37 f7 66 73 ef d9 ec c9 de 7a 36 77 7a 13 f7 e1  7.fs.....z6wz...
00000340: a1 04 db ef f7 96 3d 32 92 b2 16 8b d0 37 61 22  ......=2.....7a"
00000350: b6 20 21 0a 1b f6 0e 03 2a 48 9e 28 0f 79 0b 9a  . !.....*H.(.y..
00000360: a2 0a 5a d2 43 9b 6d 87 08 64 a6 10 bc 0e b0 34  ..Z.C.m..d.....4
00000370: 78 c5 be be 1b 96 bd 17 f2 1d 60 42 dc 43 c1 9e  x.........`B.C..
00000380: 65 4e 08 64 46 31 25 cd d6 90 31 68 c2 ca 4c f9  eN.dF1%...1h..L.
00000390: 9c 70 33 47 87 2a 7b 51 0e c9 37 1d a5 a6 39 5d  .p3G.*{Q..7...9]
000003a0: 8b c5 3e 4e 9b 57 88 0f 27 b4 46 24 c5 ba 8e cb  ..>N.W..'.F$....
000003b0: b0 24 b9 0c 7f 03 af 73 8f 5e 06 52 19 ee 0a 08  .$.....s.^.R....
000003c0: 82 8b 87 87 07 c9 8c 2c da 53 3e 1e b4 c9 21 24  .......,.S>...!$
000003d0: 54 aa 47 7f 16 d9 5d 04 c5 a6 c1 47 11 93 72 15  T.G...]....G..r.
000003e0: 74 53 f4 3e ad 32 04 33 9a cd e9 2b 01 a5 04 9c  tS.>.2.3...+....
000003f0: 35 d2 fc 81 93 b3 f2 3c 87 25 27 04 03 4f 1e 0a  5......<.%'..O..
00000400: be 82 49 32 f2 2a 61 24 11 25 51 c2 38 67 95 92  ..I2.*a$.%Q.8g..
00000410: a9 63 25 05 91 08 51 a9 d9 61 70 93 e0 ba ee 13  .c%...Q..ap.....
00000420: 7b 5f 8d 8c 1b 26 4c 2b 6a b2 93 97 64 b2 55 75  {_...&L+j...d.Uu
00000430: 72 79 8a 34 00 bb 19 d8 91 28 8a a5 71 03 5f 06  ry.4.....(..q._.
00000440: b6 f8 31 55 5a f5 46 ee b6 dc 0a a1 39 ab ba 11  ..1UZ.F.....9...
00000450: 80 66 cd 87 ec 45 9a e8 09 e2 e0 54 d5 d2 53 b4  .f...E.....T..S.
00000460: b2 6c 9e 40 e9 b4 86 0e 42 96 7b c8 51 2e 5b ba  .l.@....B.{.Q.[.
00000470: 2d 89 47 bc b8 cb fa db cd fc d9 ad 50 9d e7 70  -.G.........P..p
00000480: 28 9c 4f 07 04 e9 de 3d f5 f7 53 c7 69 fe 16 f6  (.O....=..S.i...
00000490: c5 59 1e 3a 80 19 36 46 e8 e7 d0 e6 a5 de 79 a5  .Y.:..6F......y.
000004a0: de fa a5 de 3a 52 6f 17 34 ce 8e ec bc c6 63 ef  ....:Ro.4.....c.
000004b0: d9 37 fe b3 6f 9c b3 bd bd 81 89 bc 7d e4 f5 c9  .7..o.......}...
000004c0: c0 d3 b7 cd 73 df 3d 1f 21 03 f1 42 a4 83 9c 96  ....s.=.!..B....
000004d0: a5 29 00 81 48 98 4f 90 4e 4e 6d 79 75 21 40 41  .)..H.O.NNmyu!@A
000004e0: 1c 9c 5d f7 3b 26 36 e2 c8 e9 7a cc ae a8 1c d0  ..].;&6...z.....
000004f0: 83 1e 64 ce 70 97 7f 67 c0 ae 5e 07 de fe 52 91  ..d.p..g..^...R.
00000500: 8c 62 74 65 c5 db 4e b4 2c d7 82 a5 0b d6 90 3a  .bte..N.,......:
00000510: 4c 4e 90 31 44 5b 1a 8c 84 73 8f fe 0e d9 3e 98  LN.1D[...s....>.
00000520: 49 21 63 cc c7 40 c0 8f c1 ad 48 5a cf ec 19 4f  I!c..@....HZ...O
00000530: 0f 02 59 3a 47 41 1b f8 32 a5 d5 7a 19 a3 cd b3  ..Y:GA..2..z....
00000540: 8a 7d cc 8e 4e 13 fc 39 74 45 d5 40 23 43 2c a4  .}..N..9tE.@#C,.
00000550: db 2c cb 24 0f aa 4a 40 71 a0 47 59 fd 27 35 c2  .,.$..J@q.GY.'5.
00000560: d2 9f 5b 2b e6 72 b5 e4 5e b2 2a 0b b5 18 fd c0  ..[+.r..^.*.....
00000570: 85 9a 86 b4 29 16 4d b5 db 4b ed 65 59 80 89 98  ....).M..K.eY...
00000580: db 4d f6 8d df ad 2d 25 6e f7 12 c4 d3 a5 e9 52  .M....-%n......R
00000590: 1c 2f f2 38 34 07 76 d3 1a 2c 20 e4 b4 85 69 86  ./.84.v.., ...i.
000005a0: e5 21 34 99 a2 f4 07 6e d1 8e 96 0e 2b b1 1f b5  .!4....n....+...
000005b0: 55 3a 88 4c b1 16 9e 8e b4 a7 83 1d c6 9e df 87  U:.L............
000005c0: 9b 14 bd ef ab f7 4b 95 5b f5 a3 81 62 32 1e a5  ......K.[...b2..
000005d0: 0b f9 ad f7 33 1d f5 4e c9 96 d6 b1 ec d8 32 8e  ....3..N......2.
000005e0: 39 b9 8a 32 72 14 79 c0 d7 0f 6e f6 a3 66 2c 98  9..2r.y...n..f,.
000005f0: b4 81 1e 10 76 06 60 79 37 3d b5 9d b0 62 03 79  ....v.`y7=...b.y
00000600: 45 05 21 28 d4 51 9f b8 7c 11 3a 9c 44 d5 a0 37  E.!(.Q..|.:.D..7
00000610: 9c 40 6c 9c 38 b1 75 2b 35 e4 b6 39 4e 74 2b bf  .@l.8.u+5..9Nt+.
00000620: 63 c2 6f f9 9b 4c dd c1 60 d4 8f 2a 2e 7e 87 e6  c.o..L..`..*.~..
00000630: 3c 30 ec 1c c4 f2 f6 48 53 3a 32 7e ed 35 b6 30  <0.....HS:2~.5.0
00000640: dc 4e 34 7c a8 79 11 a6 05 2d b3 ab 1b 99 bc 55  .N4|.y...-.....U
00000650: f7 a8 43 71 09 3c be 5e 2f 6d 6f 07 6a 77 26 b0  ..Cq.<.^/mo.jw&.
00000660: 87 a4 15 ca c0 79 27 37 6a 5a 32 62 49 93 aa e8  .....y'7jZ2bI...
00000670: d8 eb 41 f2 3c e1 91 5a de 89 e5 b0 b3 fe 18 c2  ..A.<..Z........
00000680: ee da 3a 33 1a db e1 43 a4 62 49 ca 71 40 c7 45  ..:3...C.bI.q@.E
00000690: 77 7b e3 a3 bd f3 cd ec b3 a5 dd f9 ad 8f 32 bc  w{............2.
000006a0: 3d c3 70 78 8e e3 70 99 e5 70 81 e7 f0 47 99 de  =.px..p..p...G..
000006b0: 59 0e 77 7f c6 e1 20 f3 43 6f 74 4a f9 a9 25 b2  Y.w... .CotJ..%.
000006c0: fe 9a e6 56 90 d3 65 e3 8a 65 99 24 39 6d 2e 04  ...V..e..e.$9m..
000006d0: 6b 3e 0c f2 4c 6a 0f ca 83 f8 e7 62 f5 d7 67 81  k>..Lj.....b..g.
000006e0: 73 77 36 4d 96 69 49 70 2b e6 65 5e 0c 14 30 d5  sw6M.iIp+.e^..0.
000006f0: fd c1 7b c6 a5 73 dd 9e 4b d1 a9 f8 a6 6d 02 12  ..{..s..K....m..
00000700: 72 b2 65 15 41 a2 de 0a 95 a9 85 17 59 35 c5 fb  r.e.A.......Y5..
00000710: b7 21 87 bb bd 43 df 0b ed 4c 56 02 cc a6 65 19  .!...C...LV...e.
00000720: a8 5f 62 9b cf df a6 28 ba c6 e7 04 0b 4b 75 68  ._b....(.....Kuh
00000730: 23 a6 32 2b 2e a7 5d ca a8 e0 8a ce 6f d0 c3 98  #.2+..].....o...
00000740: 90 bc bd f1 75 47 0b cd 94 cc aa 90 af 9f 29 11  ....uG........).
00000750: 42 8b 49 e1 a7 4f c9 6e 79 1c ea 69 4b 4a 08 96  B.I..O.ny..iKJ..
00000760: 67 e2 ce 3e 3f 73 46 1e 54 f3 7f 33 a4 4e 45 a6  g..>?sF.T..3.NE.
00000770: 95 88 91 a9 c8 7f e8 88 ea e9 ab 86 28 b8 8b ec  ............(...
00000780: 04 18 3f b8 fd eb 6e af 1a 58 3b 4b 89 89 f3 92  ..?...n..X;K....
00000790: 56 c7 cf b4 29 a0 2b dd 34 f5 f1 f2 1a 1a d4 b0  V...).+.4.......
000007a0: 25 0d 04 8d b6 31 82 f4 ea 20 ea de 3f 15 3a f0  %....1... ..?.:.
000007b0: f1 64 e2 70 07 27 ca 7c d2 a7 15 af e6 7e c6 6d  .d.p.'.|.....~.m
000007c0: 8a 33 d4 49 ef 3c 9f 23 ed 88 f7 cc 89 72 b0 9c  .3.I.<.#.....r..
000007d0: 71 fd b5 6f 47 7a 88 77 47 6b 20 18 c5 f8 cc dc  q..oGz.wGk .....
000007e0: 3b 9d 58 67 99 31 4e 39 a1 dc cf 98 7a 4a 76 9e  ;.Xg.1N9....zJv.
000007f0: 59 04 ae 05 45 26 1d 86 43 33 cb a6 10 7c 50 1a  Y...E&..C3...|P.
00000800: da 4e 96 d2 96 18 45 f9 12 53 20 ec 09 4e 23 0f  .N....E..S ..N#.
00000810: e8 87 65 77 ba 52 7c e4 25 c3 dc 8c dd 67 0c 84  ..ew.R|.%....g..
00000820: d0 70 2c 42 06 55 8f 57 13 25 cd f5 d7 08 49 89  .p,B.U.W.%....I.
00000830: 36 20 4d 0b dd 7a ea ce 80 7b df 0c d8 d3 a6 b5  6 M..z...{......
00000840: 7c f4 62 8e b0 9f 32 44 ce dc ac 6e 27 dc 87 21  |.b...2D...n'..!
00000850: 7f 83 a3 ba 4b 55 a2 8e 8c 1d 4b 22 89 ea a7 6d  ....KU....K"...m
00000860: 6e 97 f0 df 3c ce 23 0d 8b 9b 46 f2 3a 0b 19 df  n...<.#...F.:...
00000870: 69 48 a5 1d 93 1e 5d e3 58 53 98 ec 9e f6 e3 86  iH....].XS......
00000880: c9 99 f2 95 dc ee 83 c8 cd 9d 25 20 8e c4 bf 47  ..........% ...G
00000890: a7 b7 93 1f c1 05 c8 36 bb 0a 81 e6 1a a9 bf d1  .......6........
000008a0: b5 cd 9e d3 4b c5 76 ff bd 9f 99 03 e7 71 e5 53  ....K.v......q.S
000008b0: 1b 57 e9 f3 c0 23 f5 ac bd 70 77 13 b8 be 79 18  .W...#...pw...y.
000008c0: 3d 31 f2 61 6f af fd 54 77 33 eb fb 99 f5 db 6b  =1.ao..Tw3.....k
000008d0: c7 27 7f 59 38 50 00 3a 2a 93 37 50 33 e0 bb 85  .'.Y8P.:*.7P3...
000008e0: 56 d7 4f dd 0a 93 39 d1 ce c3 ec 5d 18 34 27 f3  V.O...9....].4'.
000008f0: 28 26 ad 4b a8 c9 64 e6 3f c5 2b dc c2 65 d6 16  (&.K..d.?.+..e..
00000900: b2 dd 3b 28 df 9d f1 d2 5d 9e ec 72 b2 84 fe 7e  ..;(....]..r...~
00000910: 47 f5 3b e0 18 53 34 d7 25 4e 89 4c c6 17 2f 05  G.;..S4.%N.L../.
00000920: 51 69 c1 97 8b 45 09 56 00 ee 0c e0 4d 0d c3 25  Qi...E.V....M..%
00000930: d5 28 39 58 39 e3 03 11 5f e1 c6 d2 9c ae 45 c5  .(9X9..._.....E.
00000940: d0 84 cb 2c d3 9f d9 df d7 e1 84 9d 78 3f 83 5c  ...,........x?.\
00000950: 08 af 78 9b e5 de 91 74 a3 60 27 d6 9a 2b 47 56  ..x....t.`'..+GV
00000960: 37 a5 2f 7a 23 9b 8e e4 fe f3 27 d3 83 e8 22 9b  7./z#.....'...".
00000970: 82 d9 b9 d5 8a c0 70 ec dd f1 2c 06 23 52 26 c4  ......p...,.#R&.
00000980: a3 fe d9 a4 4d 6e ba eb db 00 15 0d 1c 6f e4 a3  ....Mn.......o..
00000990: cb a1 0f f0 ab de 54 5f 55 f6 43 69 5c 5d c1 fc  ......T_U.Ci\]..
000009a0: 5d 9f 7b ff 6d c1 0c 76 d0 bd e3 f8 2a ab 2b 69  ].{.m..v....*.+i
000009b0: 06 6e ea 77 b8 c0 bd d6 eb 1f 89 0e 83 a1 11 20  .n.w........... 
000009c0: c5 65 7a 05 c6 44 a1 34 d4 f5 60 bb d0 be 83 b5  .ez..D.4..`.....
000009d0: 4e dc 9c d1 c1 e4 da f1 0f 91 77 79 08 ef bd 73  N.........wy...s
000009e0: dc 9e 39 dd 98 ea ed 06 c5 f9 5b ac 45 12 c3 14  ..9.......[.E...
000009f0: a0 83 cc 67 6a 7d 8e f2 9b 63 4b b3 d0 0c de 06  ...gj}...cK.....
00000a00: da 18 22 bc 5f c2 98 dc c3 8f d1 95 50 2a b6 a1  .."._.......P*..
00000a10: 19 22 40 a0 d6 a9 cb 77 fa f8 79 cc d4 a7 c6 48  ."@....w..y....H
00000a20: fa e7 5a e3 52 6d 7e bf 01 c7 72 82 2b 68 df 78  ..Z.Rm~...r.+h.x
00000a30: cb e4 b1 f2 ab 9b 51 84 d9 a1 a5 7c 39 a0 82 66  ......Q....|9..f
00000a40: 19 a9 1f 67 93 8c 21 e7 5c 2e 29 92 df 16 6e 85  ...g..!.\.)...n.
00000a50: a4 3f 76 50 21 13 ca 84 5d 45 3c cf 7a b7 d8 74  .?vP!...]E<.z..t
00000a60: 7a 63 b1 d0 67 ce 7d 9f 10 c6 5c 5b 27 2d a5 49  zc..g.}...\['-.I
00000a70: 05 61 75 94 93 9f 77 f9 ca 03 42 26 44 11 ea 1f  .au...w...B&D...
00000a80: cf 4c 7f 5f e5 38 a6 fd a3 ac 50 97 b1 f6 98 e0  .L._.8....P.....
00000a90: ab 7d bc 46 fb dd 1a dd de 42 bd d8 dc 4a 99 fb  .}.F.....B...J..
00000aa0: 0b 7f 49 f7 99 76 fa 87 4b 83 4d 86 81 d0 be 7d  ..I..v..K.M....}
00000ab0: d7 78 40 67 db a1 a8 5b 5b a8 f0 55 2e 4b d4 f1  .x@g...[[..U.K..
00000ac0: b5 ff 3b f1 3e 8c 32 a8 d8 dc 05 aa 99 21 94 c0  ..;.>.2......!..
00000ad0: 25 71 14 6f 3f e5 70 85 d6 d0 3f 2a f5 8f c9 fc  %q.o?.p...?*....
00000ae0: 61 89 3b 3b f1 b1 ba 7c 43 5d da 12 52 23 5c 67  a.;;...|C]..R#\g
00000af0: 90 08 87 9f cb dd dd de f7 83 9c c7 01 ad 3b 31  ..............;1
00000b00: f3 4b a9 ef b6 3b ff 0a c5 4d e6 44 13 42 b0 40  .K...;...M.D.B.@
00000b10: eb dc fc 4c 60 ee 82 cc f5 ce ef b0 36 a5 d8 7f  ...L`.......6...
00000b20: 1a 93 86 77 f8 3e 39 c1 0e 09 3b 28 9c b0 38 fb  ...w.>9...;(..8.
00000b30: c3 c3 c9 ef 06 3d 77 f1 7d 87 f5 9f ab 48 a7 85  .....=w.}....H..
00000b40: f1 6d bc 17 a4 3b 07 c1 ce 00 9c 41 37 f7 36 10  .m...;.....A7.6.
00000b50: db 39 f4 a1 a1 3f 56 55 f0 2f 02 bc 50 68 57 d2  .9...?VU./..PhW.
00000b60: 02 ff af 99 ab 5b 6a e5 86 c1 d7 79 8b ce f4 82  .....[j....y....
00000b70: c3 0c c9 81 84 9c b6 87 8b f6 31 60 a6 37 21 d9  ..........1`.7!.
00000b80: 40 86 0d 9b c9 2e a5 0c d3 77 af 6d c9 b6 64 cb  @........w.m..d.
00000b90: 6b ef e6 40 3b dc 90 44 f6 ca fa 24 d9 d6 cf 3e  k..@;..D...$...>
00000ba0: 3f 54 df fd 43 f3 f2 b8 fd a2 85 98 13 49 40 25  ?T..C........I@%
00000bb0: 4b 85 13 c9 82 61 34 59 02 c9 5a a3 c5 28 83 5a  K....a4Y..Z..(.Z
00000bc0: b6 21 ff 96 98 2d 88 50 52 a2 f0 f7 8c 6e cf da  .!...-.PR....n..
00000bd0: aa ae d6 5d b5 91 95 dc fd 9c d1 f6 7e 50 b2 4a  ...]........~P.J
00000be0: 7a 9b 55 d2 db 9c 92 de f6 2a 29 fc 2a f9 0d 2f  z.U......*).*../
00000bf0: 89 bd da 36 b1 14 45 14 85 fb 1d 65 d1 bf e6 69  ...6..E....e...i
00000c00: 99 26 4e 8b 54 71 5a a2 8b d3 ac 32 5a 0a 73 33  .&N.TqZ....2Z.s3
00000c10: 30 ab 4f 6c f6 fb 46 59 65 65 b6 fc c0 fd fa a1  0.Ol..FYee......
00000c20: 4e 70 66 6c c1 89 99 11 15 1e 99 4b 77 0e 61 35  Npfl.......Kw.a5
00000c30: 74 3d ea b7 27 e5 90 cd 82 60 fb 70 c7 2d 76 bb  t=..'....`.p.-v.
00000c40: 55 1f bd df 9e 38 b7 6d 8f ae ac b0 43 2a 2b 97  U....8.m....C*+.
00000c50: 12 a7 92 33 88 92 a7 09 a2 ac 6b 9a e4 3d 93 78  ...3......k..=.x
00000c60: 35 67 53 14 fa 25 38 f6 c4 65 12 91 5b 42 42 4a  5gS..%8..e..[BBJ
00000c70: 13 fe 6c 21 98 e1 69 06 a0 28 f1 22 7d a2 bb cc  ..l!..i..(."}...
00000c80: c9 ed 32 23 b4 cb 3e 89 81 07 d1 de 94 9c d5 bd  ..2#..>.........
00000c90: 1e b7 9d 3a 5f 60 8d 71 c9 42 fe 17 ee d0 de 5a  ...:_`.q.B.....Z
00000ca0: 82 9a 34 bd c0 29 f9 0e d6 1a 46 d3 cd ec e4 98  ..4..)....F.....
00000cb0: 43 6e ed 99 38 92 8b 11 47 ea 41 aa cb bd 96 50  Cn..8...G.A....P
00000cc0: 56 5c 85 56 8a a3 cc f9 0a 1c 83 0b 9c 41 30 90  V\.V.........A0.
00000cd0: da b2 b9 87 5c 5e 98 bf d9 af e7 37 b6 8e da 25  ....\^.....7...%
00000ce0: 15 e4 00 3e 8b fb 43 11 42 54 28 45 55 03 c8 f7  ...>..C.BT(EU...
00000cf0: 4d d3 3d 9a d3 de 4a f7 b2 d5 3b b5 f4 0d d1 8e  M.=...J...;.....
00000d00: a6 fd 3b a2 7c 38 ae de 5a 75 39 ac d8 ea fc ed  ..;.|8..Zu9.....
00000d10: cf 87 d2 ec 37 2c 64 ef bf 96 12 4b 94 45 8a 90  ....7,d....K.E..
00000d20: 97 90 b2 e0 79 ea 84 22 52 f5 12 b0 9b f3 5b 0d  ....y.."R.....[.
00000d30: 01 00 6b 60 62 ea cb 79 ef 99 ee 0e d4 54 3c bf  ..k`b..y.....T<.
00000d40: d2 9f c0 c7 a1 c7 86 06 06 78 93 40 6f 3d 65 94  .........x.@o=e.
00000d50: ea 88 bb 73 5c de 6c 7a b5 34 d1 c3 b9 09 22 92  ...s\.lz.4....".
00000d60: c7 9b 08 22 89 32 42 79 84 50 72 9a 8b 1d 49 21  ...".2By.Pr...I!
00000d70: 0b 21 6c 64 9e aa 0b 6c 7d 0c 20 48 94 85 71 23  .!ld...l}. H..q#
00000d80: d2 5d 87 53 90 a1 56 93 16 bf 2c 7d 95 88 42 b1  .].S..V...,}..B.
00000d90: 7d b9 3f 18 22 0d 21 7e 50 5b b3 6b 72 cb 35 24  }.?.".!~P[.kr.5$
00000da0: 4c f4 e6 ee a2 91 18 a3 12 c3 5c 6e 89 0b 22 da  L.........\n..".
00000db0: f0 89 51 04 8a db b1 38 64 74 71 8e 5a be bd d4  ..Q....8dtq.Z...
00000dc0: 43 78 aa db 75 75 c5 25 61 09 cc ef 8f 8b 8b d4  Cx..uu.%a.......
00000dd0: 4f 34 3c 4e 82 40 73 08 02 31 be 83 29 9d 4a f3  O4<N.@s..1..).J.
00000de0: 9a 96 38 25 59 96 02 4c a5 f2 ee 4c 5c bf 97 17  ..8%Y..L...L\...
00000df0: 50 71 e9 29 61 6c 77 99 cc 1f d0 c7 78 f9 62 25  Pq.)alw.....x.b%
00000e00: ba 28 59 f8 09 6a 7b fa fd 80 9a 6f fb 52 d7 46  .(Y..j{....o.R.F
00000e10: ca 7c 2e ff 75 c9 3c fd a9 e9 49 0f f8 e9 5f 0f  .|..u.<...I..._.
00000e20: 60 c6 d1 c9 22 67 b4 92 0c cd 46 8f 26 dc a7 35  `..."g....F.&..5
00000e30: 61 74 d6 46 83 27 56 58 a6 9b 55 4b 0a ff 7b 17  at.F.'VX..UK..{.
00000e40: 8b 73 9d 6b c0 5c 02 e3 50 cd 84 83 b9 c7 22 6a  .s.k.\..P....."j
00000e50: 20 5a 7b 81 6e e0 bc ba b7 16 fc 8f 7f 90 ab ad   Z{.n...........
00000e60: 18 6f dc 38 19 e8 c3 90 dd c6 73 b1 3f ac 9e df  .o.8......s.?...
00000e70: a6 9a 3f 63 a3 34 88 6b 45 7f 74 e7 16 8c 50 e3  ..?c.4.kE.t...P.
00000e80: 68 dd 4c 96 ad f3 ef df 97 22 37 a0 93 9c d1 ca  h.L......"7.....
00000e90: c3 3b 98 e5 be ae 1e 56 75 8e 01 a9 94 4e e3 8a  .;.....Vu....N..
00000ea0: 7b 5b fc ec 44 14 9a 3f 74 45 25 6e 5a 5d 23 92  {[..D..?tE%nZ]#.
00000eb0: 43 4e a0 f3 40 9e 30 4e c6 02 b4 e9 58 bd b4 a6  CN..@.0N....X...
00000ec0: 69 79 ad b6 90 16 37 34 c8 13 58 29 84 f5 38 d4  iy....74..X)..8.
00000ed0: fe 71 e7 4a 56 44 91 f2 cc 99 6f 38 10 93 c7 d1  .q.JVD....o8....
00000ee0: 18 bb 87 1e 57 9b dd 4b eb 9a 92 5e 6d 55 00 7c  ....W..K...^mU.|
00000ef0: 74 89 1e a1 64 e3 9a 37 73 64 d5 58 5e 6f b4 38  t...d..7sd.X^o.8
00000f00: 86 bf 6d da fd aa 7b 22 8f 0d 4a 50 ff cb b7 05  ..m...{"..JP....
00000f10: 62 e4 e4 d8 fe d7 e3 4d 98 9f 23 91 83 55 d7 ad  b......M..#..U..
00000f20: d6 8f 7b 63 be a6 fb 22 99 96 4b a6 ee 68 a0 32  ..{c..."..K..h.2
00000f30: 4b ab cf b8 45 84 4d 09 99 c6 dc c8 c1 3a e1 10  K...E.M......:..
00000f40: 7a 7f 38 31 64 a6 ed 59 10 6e 80 9f bb 04 d0 14  z.81d..Y.n......
00000f50: 2e d1 1a 11 c3 f0 95 02 d4 48 a1 4e d0 73 eb f5  .........H.N.s..
00000f60: 94 e6 0c 97 d6 b4 fc e9 8f 02 8e 0d 3a 80 ba 7d  ............:..}
00000f70: d0 b7 a5 c1 b7 2f 16 a4 e6 8e 84 e6 e7 4a ba e1  ...../.......J..
00000f80: 70 7d c3 dc 55 ee ac ed d4 57 66 1d 2a fe a4 68  p}..U....Wf.*..h
00000f90: 16 ee be 04 4e 0b 97 dd 25 ed 01 da 74 08 6a c1  ....N...%...t.j.
00000fa0: 99 7f fe db 36 41 c5 8e 4e a5 02 90 2c 13 6b 99  ....6A..N...,.k.
00000fb0: 5f 68 c3 e4 8e 57 84 a1 a4 ce c2 f9 68 92 40 2e  _h...W......h.@.
00000fc0: 6b 02 4b 27 9c c5 c6 2f b2 94 59 50 e6 17 94 02  k.K'.../..YP....
00000fd0: a0 e5 04 e7 a2 ab 98 51 9c 48 77 76 be 87 95 04  .......Q.Hwv....
00000fe0: 29 42 8e ad 77 f7 16 5e 56 3d e4 27 20 de 00 df  )B..w..^V=.' ...
00000ff0: 80 b0 f4 bb 6b a8 cd 74 5c ee 24 2b 95 43 0d b3  ....k..t\.$+.C..
00001000: 0e 5e 2a 50 76 bb 34 47 1d 5f 52 3a a1 d3 c4 f0  .^*Pv.4G._R:....
00001010: 8b b5 1d d0 54 da 53 75 10 68 c1 9c 5b 9c b5 5f  ....T.Su.h..[.._
00001020: 45 01 1e 0b 3f 4f ed ce 64 14 29 da af 62 ef 64  E...?O..d.)..b.d
00001030: c7 d9 8b 0e 1f e7 be 4d 8e 83 9d 8c 0d 8a 37 37  .......M......77
00001040: 36 02 6e 05 7c 08 7e 17 75 2c 29 2f b1 0a 82 0e  6.n.|.~.u,)/....
00001050: a8 22 ab 83 f6 e4 a8 de 8c e2 9a 5c ad 35 99 96  .".........\.5..
00001060: ba ef c6 8d a2 17 64 36 6a 7c e4 0c 68 29 c2 39  ......d6j|..h).9
00001070: 2c 34 9c 2a e2 28 6e 26 71 6c c5 ce c1 d3 1c 60  ,4.*.(n&ql.....`
00001080: af a2 89 9b 54 12 8b a5 69 21 b0 c9 a6 40 df de  ....T...i!...@..
00001090: 3f 49 26 2b b4 2c c9 f6 78 a2 2c 01 29 c7 4b 70  ?I&+.,..x.,.).Kp
000010a0: 4d bb 30 52 4c 7b 17 29 4c b2 df 6d 36 75 55 22  M.0RL{.)L..m6uU"
000010b0: c0 be b5 df 95 ac fd 2e b7 f6 bb 78 ed 94 69 f5  ...........x..i.
000010c0: 5b c8 f6 c9 a0 91 1a c6 0c f7 31 65 19 95 84 a1  [.........1e....
000010d0: b0 92 12 20 3f 19 01 41 6f 28 e3 60 b1 25 9a c3  ... ?..Ao(.`.%..
000010e0: a0 74 15 62 e1 44 27 63 f9 f1 06 98 e4 bd 04 3d  .t.b.D'c.......=
000010f0: 2e ce 78 2a f7 76 32 27 88 6c 20 af 17 42 d8 03  ..x*.v2'.l ..B..
00001100: db 66 bd 53 f7 68 7d 36 c1 d0 2d 7c f1 1e d4 cb  .f.S.h}6..-|....
00001110: 06 cd 69 6e 17 9f db 4d dc 5f 37 a2 9e 2c 1a bc  ..in...M._7..,..
00001120: 87 e9 a7 f0 3c 10 48 22 a5 92 6a b1 b0 27 50 7e  ....<.H"..j..'P~
00001130: d9 c5 8f a9 9c 01 7d 2c 09 05 89 8f 9e 08 25 83  ......},......%.
00001140: 3f 45 31 16 a7 1f 16 81 ba 4e bc 6e 49 48 a8 a4  ?E1......N.nIH..
00001150: 89 c3 a4 4a 9a b2 c9 d3 45 2b 37 1d e7 df 83 77  ...J....E+7....w
00001160: b8 f1 f8 ca 4c d7 e6 dc 37 cd 53 48 66 83 66 7f  ....L...7.SHf.f.
00001170: 6e e7 8b 2b 6c 2f e9 5e 77 5d 17 cf 48 48 af 17  n..+l/.^w]..HH..
00001180: 48 ba 7b 56 e7 13 75 5d d9 a7 89 17 4b 3b af 02  H.{V..u]....K;..
00001190: fc 49 9d 37 e5 90 bc 66 e0 37 24 dc 1c 77 f7 f7  .I.7...f.7$..w..
000011a0: a6 7c 4e 26 9c af 91 50 81 a0 44 95 a2 bb da 56  .|N&...P..D....V
000011b0: 67 d6 22 34 f6 c6 14 fe 40 ed 58 b3 f7 4f 65 de  g."4....@.X..Oe.
000011c0: d7 d6 1e d7 d8 54 67 e6 f9 ba 05 aa 56 51 4d 6b  .....Tg.....VQMk
000011d0: fd df 4c dd 00 ce ce 4b 89 ab a6 2b 27 ee ba ed  ..L....K...+'...
000011e0: d9 b9 79 03 e4 aa fb 72 d6 1d 5f 2a 7d 10 3e 3b  ..y....r.._*}.>;
000011f0: bf 30 e3 7b 87 be 36 5b 3a 16 3e 16 8c 53 fc fd  .0.{..6[:.>..S..
00001200: fe f3 ae 52 a7 55 32 da bc 3f 6e 53 6d a6 ba 6b  ...R.U2..?nSm..k
00001210: 1b 58 b8 f1 02 7c 75 16 7b 49 be 75 2f 2f 54 53  .X...|u.{I.u//TS
00001220: d4 70 e3 f8 10 f1 43 9e 6f 10 08 38 64 08 14 38  .p....C.o..8d..8
00001230: 64 3c 20 38 c1 48 58 3c c7 3f 14 1c f2 6e b6 1f  d< 8.HX<.?...n..
00001240: 0e 8e f6 38 a5 a8 18 da 42 38 0c ed 28 1c cc c8  ...8....B8..(...
00001250: e1 00 58 e6 c6 4a fe fa b3 cd 42 33 3c cc 2a c8  ..X..J....B3<.*.
00001260: 88 01 28 9c 62 13 64 fc 38 44 4e b7 08 11 97 8f  ..(.b.d.8DN.....
00001270: b4 08 1d 70 79 d9 97 62 82 d4 85 78 20 f5 28 2c  ...py..b...x .(,
00001280: 70 ec 70 1c 3c 8b 63 31 58 7e b6 6d 00 cb c3 ac  p.p.<.c1X~.m....
00001290: 83 8d 19 84 c7 29 16 c2 66 18 8b cd e9 56 22 22  .....)..f....V""
000012a0: f4 91 56 d2 56 fb 9d 7e a9 68 29 3a 8e be 10 19  ..V.V..~.h):....
000012b0: 47 3f 0a 15 37 7a 38 22 94 d1 b1 68 7c fb 6c 7b  G?..7z8"...h|.l{
000012c0: b1 4c 0f b3 98 60 d4 40 64 4e b1 9a 60 8e f1 28  .L...`.@dN..`..(
000012d0: 9d 6e 39 22 56 e5 96 63 af cd 92 d4 cc dd af 0f  .n9"V..c........
000012e0: 0c 20 e8 91 3b 10 14 8b 18 c8 cb a4 e9 9e 5d 28  . ..;.........](
000012f0: b8 7f fe 05 52 19 e0 2a 1e 60 00 00              ....R..*.`..
```

I tried using this resource...

http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2012/01/viewing-chrome-cache-easy-way.html

but it seems as though it isn't working anymore. Anyone know how I can decode this? This is almost 60 hours worth of work just gone.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

If your wordpress is on the web you could download a cached copy of your website... that's if Google has indexed it?

Answer (score 0):

"1f 8b 08" is the file signature for a GZipped file. Copy out the file from the cache and give it a "GZ" extension. You should then be able to open it using "WinZip" or a similar application. Extract the file that results and this should be your decoded CSS file.